# Numpy - linear algebra

Tags: numpy

I have two matrices: quantities and displacements.

The problem is as follows:

```
[0.011 * x + 0.0295 * y + 0.080 * w + 0.182 * z] = [-4.31, 8.15, 0.83]

[0.011 * x + 0.0220 * y + 0.098 * w + 0.180 * z] = [-3.70, 6.30, 1.03]

[0.013 * x + 0.0230 * y + 0.108 * w + 0.172 * z] = [-3.89, 6.33, 0.52]

[0.013 * x + 0.0230 * y + 0.105 * w + 0.175 * z] = [-3.38, 5.55, 0.54]
```

In numpy:

```
quantities = np matrix ([[0.011, 0.0295, 0.080, 0.182], [0.011, 0.022, 0.098, 0.180], [0.013, 0.023, 0.108, 0.172], [0.013, 0.023, 0.105, 0.175]))

displacements = np matrix ([[-4.31, 8.15, 0.83], [-3.7, 6.3, 1.03], [-3.89, 6.33, 0.52] , [-3.38, 5.55, 0.54]])
```

To obtain the displacement `[-4.37, 7.44, 1.01]`, what are the values ​​of x, y, w, z used?

That is:

```
[ax + by + cw + dz] = [-4.37, 7.44, 1.01]
```

What are the values ​​of `a, b, c` and `d`?

Comment: ` np.linalg.inv(quantities) @ displacement`?

Comment: `xywz = np.matrix([[-4.37, 7.44, 1.01]])`
`(np.linalg.inv(quantities) @ displacements) @ xywz.T`

Comment: yeah you then should compute a, b, c, d using there coefficients, assume resultate array is **R**, then

`xywz = np.matrix([[-4.37, 7.44, 1.01]])`

`R @ xywz.T`